# Ubuntu 22.04 Mate switch to Gnome

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-mate

In my work - I got a VM (on a special server for it) with Ubuntu 22.04 Mate that I connect to it with RDP (I have windows 10).

I don't like the Mate desktop.
How on earth can I switch to Gnome?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I am surprised 'cause I vastly prefer Mate but ...

First, be absolutely certain you have a good backup and/or (better) snapshot of your VM.  If you don't have access to the VM host, you will need to have your host administrator make one and prepare him for what you are about to do (this is a pretty big change - lots could potentially go wrong).

Log in to your target:
[image: Mate Desktop]
Press Ctrl+Alt+T to bring up the terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo apt update && \
sudo apt -y install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

You will receive a notice:
[image: first popup]

Select OK
You will then be prompted to select a display manager: gdm3 or lightdm:

[image: second popup]

You may use either but gdm3 is the default for gnome, lightdm is the default for Mate.  Your choice.  I am selecting gdm3 for this demonstration.

The installation will then proceed and take several minutes.  As a said, a big change.

[image: installation proceeds]

When completed enter:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Wait a few minutes and then log in. If all went well...
[image: gnome desktop]
In the event that everything does not work the way you want after the change, you will need to roll back to the snapshot you made earlier.

I encountered no errors or issues with this procedure but my Mate Desktop was a virgin build.  Your mileage may very depending on what has been installed on yours.  Of particular concern should be your RDP service since that is your mode of access.

If space is tight, you can free up about 85Mb by

```
sudo apt purge mate-desktop --autoremove
```

as @Inee suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did it, but it didn't help - still, mate. 
BTW, I just got used to the gnome, so it is easier and faster for me.

Comment: On a freshly installed MATE just converted to Unity, I found this procedure to work well and I could save 135 MB with the purge at the end. Note that the MATE splash screen before opening Unity remains but it adds a personal touch, you could say...

Answer (score -1):

yes you can
first run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`
reboot after
then if you want to remove mate run `sudo apt purge mate-desktop --autoremove`

note I do not know what the server you are connecting to is using I answered as if you were on a local computer also this may be against your works rules